# JMeter: HTTPJavaImpl clogs the logs with redundant errors

Tags: jmeter, error-logging

While running a stress test against an HTTP server which has an authentication process (401+challenge,200) I get the JMeter (v2.11) log full of these:

2015/02/17 13:52:48 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://w1-load1:8080/perftest/login
2015/02/17 13:53:04 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://w1-load1:8080/perftest/login 
2015/02/17 13:53:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: Error Response Code: 401

I don't mind the HTTP 401 , I handle those in the next request (by design)

in the BeanShell post processor I read these 401 and "make" them ok (using  prev.setResponseOK() ).
setting the response code in the BeanShell doesn't prevent the initial IOException.
The problem occur also when not using BeanShell at all.

However, under stress,with many threads, these errors cost me 10% of JMeter output rate (tested against a service which doesn't return 401).
I saw that the rate of error in the JMeter log is approximately 20 lines/sec.
tested also with JMeter remote agents.

can some one explain how to avoid those log lines or how I can remove them ?
if I fail to write the BeanShell directive the log gets even larger exception:
and the request is considered a failure.

Comment: I start to see now: its probably a bug in the JMeter code.   HTTPJAvaImpl#readResponse  uses HttpURLConnection.getContentLength() which set the private "rememberedException" to IOException upon 401.  the next call to HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() will throw that exception.

Comment: Can you provide link to that source?

Comment: its Apache's JMeter HTTPJavaImpl class and Oracle JDK HttpURLConnection class. both are open to the public . the problem happens before BeanShell. so its not related.

Answer (score 1):

The Log Messages format is probably

```
#log_format=%{time:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %5.5{priority} - %{category}: %{message} %{throwable}
```

In this case the logging is not from BeanShell but jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.

You can control this logging in the [JMeter properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) file or user properties file.

The logging configuration file is well documented in the source of the [jmeter.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/bin/jmeter.properties#L241) file.

You can turn down logging by controlling at the package or class level.

Anything that is below this package name will only log on FATAL_ERROR

```
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http=FATAL_ERROR
```

Or at that class level, only impacting the HTTPJavaImpl

```
log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl=FATAL_ERROR
```

I tested the following using this [load test and JMX](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11663) just changing the Implementation to see the different log statements.

Finally in your case your are using HTTPJavaImpl, if you were to use HTTPClient4 the logging is a bit different and does not seem to log 401 return values or treat them as exceptions.

Comment: thanks. I actually found that yesterday. that will keep the log file size down but it will not prevent the amount of exceptions thrown and handled.

Answer (score 0):

jmeter.properties: you can change the Sampler implementation:
jmeter.httpsampler=HTTPSampler2